# How to change the default screen size of mobile view in materialize css?

Tags: css, materialize

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col s12 m6 l6">

     </div>
</div>
```

default screen size for mobile view is <=600px in materialize css but how to increase this screen size as <=700px?

Comment: you want to override the default materialize css?

Comment: yes i want to override.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override your materialize css then you have to use media query for this like in your custom css file which should be defined below your `materialize.css` file

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 701px){
  .s12{
    width:100%
  }
  .hide-on-small-only{
    display:none;
  }
  /* other css...    */
}
```

Comment: but '.hide-on-small-only' class not hide.

Comment: @vijay you have to write all the css inside this media rule which you want to override. See Updated!

Answer (score 0):

find all lines in your `materialize.css` file ,

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px)
```

and replace it with below :

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 701px)
```

Comment: but do not change the materialize library

Comment: ok then , whatever class u are using , add inside this  media query  `@media only screen and (min-width: 701px)` and redefine define classes that u are using.

Answer (score 0):

You check in the _variables.scss in the component folder of their library. Hit ctrl+f then type Media Query Ranges. You'll be able to set the limits you want.